# GWT RequestBuilder: How to handle pdf?

Tags: gwt

I am sending request on server, and server returns StreamingOutput (wriring bytes of pdf file)
In onResponseRecieved i need to handle this file and start download. How to start to download this file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448840/file-download-using-requestbuilder-of-gwt

Answer (score 0):

I supose you dont need to process that data in javascript, do you?

If you just want to download the file or display it in the browser, create a button in your page so as when the user clicks it will show in a new window or the user will asked to save the file:

```
final String url = "http://gwtquery.googlecode.com/git/README.txt";
String name = "README.txt";

Anchor link1 = new Anchor(name);
RootPanel.get().add(link1);
link1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.open(url, "_blank", "");
  }
});
```